# Dreaded CORS issue with WebAPI and token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I swear this has happened so many times to me that I actually **hate** CORS.
I have just split my application in two so that one handles just the API side of things and the other handles the client side stuff.
I have done this before, so I knew that I needed to make sure CORS was enabled and allowed all, so I set this up in **WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

    // Enable CORS
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

    // Web API configuration and services
    var formatters = config.Formatters;
    var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
    var serializerSettings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

    // Remove XML formatting
    formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Configure our JSON output
    serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    serializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    serializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    serializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

    // Configure the API route
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

As you can see, my first line Enables the CORS, so it should work.
If I open my client application and query the API, it does indeed work (without the EnableCors I get the expected CORS error.
The problem is my **/token** is still getting a CORS error. Now I am aware that /token endpoint is not part of the WebAPI, so I created my own OAuthProvider (which I must point out is being used in other places just fine) and that looks like this:

```
public class OAuthProvider<TUser> : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    where TUser : class, IUser
{
    private readonly string publicClientId;
    private readonly UserService<TUser> userService;

    public OAuthProvider(string publicClientId, UserService<TUser> userService)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");

        if (userService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userService");

        this.publicClientId = publicClientId; 
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var user = await this.userService.FindByUserNameAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var oAuthIdentity = this.userService.CreateIdentity(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        var cookiesIdentity = this.userService.CreateIdentity(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        var properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == this.publicClientId)
        {
            var redirectUri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
            var expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, redirectUri.PathAndQuery);

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == redirectUri.AbsoluteUri)
                context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName }
        };

        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```

As you can see, In the **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** method I enable CORS access to everything again. This should work for all requests to /token but it doesn't.
When I try to login from my client application I get a CORS error.
Chrome shows this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62605/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50098' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

and Firefox shows this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:62605/token. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). 
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:62605/token. (Reason: CORS request failed).

For testing purposes, I decided to use fiddler to see if I could see anything else that might give me a clue as to what is happening. When I try to login, FIddler shows a response code as 400 and if I look at the raw response I can see the error:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

which is strange, because the data I am sending has not changed and was working fine before the split.
I decided to use the Composer on fiddler and replicated what I expect the POST request to look like.
When I Execute it, it works fine and I get a response code of 200.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

## Update 1

Just for reference, the request from my client app looks like this:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:62605/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:62605
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:50098
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:50098/account/signin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

from the composer, it looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:62605/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Host: localhost:62605
Content-Length: 67

grant_type=password&userName=foo&password=bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was no issue with CORS at all. I had an interceptor class that was modifying the headers incorrectly. I suggest for future reference, anyone else having these issues, if you have your CORS set up either in WebConfig.cs or your Startup class or even the web.config then you need to check that nothing is modifying your headers. If it is, disable it and test again.

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: what does your interceptor look like now?

Answer (score 8):

Inside of

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
```

Get rid of this:

```
 context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

Currently you are doing the CORS thing twice. Once with .EnableCors and also again by writing the header in your token endpoint.

For what it's worth, in my OWIN startup class I have this at the very top:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

I also do NOT have it in my WebAPI register method, as I'm letting the OWIN startup handle it.

Comment: I was running into this issue with a c# web api being called from an angular app.  Moving **app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);** to the top of **public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {} ** did the trick.  Thanks Bill.

Comment: The `UseCors` extension is from the `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` NuGet package.

Answer (score 4):

Since `OAuthAuthorizationServer` runs as an Owin middleware you must use the appropriate package `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` to enable CORS that works with any middleware in the pipeline. Keep in mind that WebApi & Mvc are just middleware themselves in regards to the owin pipeline.

So remove `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));` from your WebApiConfig and add the following to your startup class.
**Note** `app.UseCors` it must precede the `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer`

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
```

Comment: Yep can't have it in both, the correct place is in startup.cs, mine started working once I took it out of webapiconfig.cs

Answer (score 3):

@r3plica

I had this problem, and it is like Bill said.

Put the line "app.UseCors" at the very top in Configuration method()
(before ConfigureOAuth(app) is enough)

Example:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureWebApi(config);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I hope you don't mind some feedback to improve your answer. First, you can't `@` someone in questions or answers, just comments, so that's just noise you can delete. Adding an answer that provides an example for another answer is good, I recommend clearly linking to the answer in that case. `To add to [Bill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33265170/1677912)...`, for clarity. Good luck!

Comment: This was exactly the issue i was encountering. I was wondering if you had any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

We ran into a similar situation and ended up specifying some CORS data in the system.webServer node of the web.config in order to pass the preflight check. Your situation is slightly different than ours but maybe that would help you as well.

Here's what we added:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I tried that, that wasn't the issue. Eventually I figured it out. I will post the solution. It was nothing to do with CORs as I expected :(

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the issue in my development environment